# Omit XML Declaration in DataSet.WriteXMLSchema

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, xml-serialization, declaration

i need to serialize a dataset in c# to xml for sending the data to a webservice. I cannot change the webservice so my code has to be changed to fit the requirements of the webservice.

I use `dataset.WriteXmlSchema(stream)` to write the schema and add `dataset.WriteXml(stream)` to add the data itself.

The result now looks like following:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xs:schema id='DocumentElement' xmlns='' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' ...
```

Is there a chance to get rid of the `<?xml version='1.0'?>` declaration?
I need to encapsulate the XML result of the dataset into other xml data and the xml declation breaks the data i need to send. I didn't want to start with fuzzy string handling and i thought there must be something more straight forward.

Thanks

MadMaxapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no way to omit the xml declaration. I've implemented some code to remove the first line of the xml. Not nice but it works.